# what are the different node js npm install options

Tags: node.js, express

what is the difference between

```
 npm install express 
 npm install -g express
```

if you can also point me to a link which explains these options it will be very useful

Comment: I use npm install express --save a lot. It writes to your local package.json for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

> npm has two modes of operation:
>
> global mode: npm installs packages into the install prefix at prefix/lib/node_modules and bins are installed in prefix/bin.
>
> local mode:
>   npm installs packages into the current project directory, which defaults to the current working directory. Packages are installed to ./node_modules, and bins are installed to ./node_modules/.bin.
>   Local mode is the default.
>
> Use --global or -g on any command to operate in global mode instead.

The Google search phrase I used was:

```
npm options "-g"
```